# Is it possible that declare method as a Variable in java

Tags: java, android, variables, generics, interface

Here is a code from googlemap cluster utility

```
private ClusterManager.OnClusterItemInfoWindowClickListener<T> mItemInfoWindowClickListener;
```

ClusterManager is a class.

```
private final ClusterManager<T> mClusterManager;
```

OnClusterItemInfoWindowClickListener is interface.

```
public interface OnClusterItemInfoWindowClickListener<T extends ClusterItem> {
    public void onClusterItemInfoWindowClick(T item);
}
```

The question is does mItemInfoWindowClickListener variable?

I can't find any  example like this. and I don't know what is the purpose of this.

It will be help full, If anyone explain this code or just link informative webpage.

Thanks.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by this: "The question is does mItemInfoWindowClickListener variable?"

Comment: it is an object variable

Comment: it is a variable referring `OnClusterItemInfoWindowClickListener` interface.. Why do you think it as a method?

Comment: By use of reflection you can achieve it.

Comment: Ok. mItemInfoWindowClickListener variable represents interface. Is it right?